# What is the purpose of local & asks functions in Reader monad

Tags: haskell, monads, reader

While I try to familiar the usage for Reader monad in Haskell, I noticed there are two similar functions provided in the `mtl` library.

`asks :: MonadReader r m => (r -> a) -> m a`

`local :: MonadReader r m => (r -> r) -> m a -> m a`

For example,

```hs
import Control.Monad.Reader

changeEnv :: String -> String
changeEnv = ("Prefix " ++)

getLength :: Reader String Int
getLength = do
  e <- ask
  return $ length e

runReader (local changeEnv getLength) "123" 
10

runReader (asks (length . changeEnv)) "123"
10

runReader (asks (length . local changeEnv id)) "123"
10
```

It seems we can compute the same result using either `asks` or `local`.

Is there any result that cannot compute from either one of them?

For now, I can only say using `local` allows me to separate the function (`changeEnv`) changing the environment and a function (`getLength`) that returns the result of the Reader. However, the same could have achieve using `asks` as well.

Is there any special reason that we need both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you were able to replace `local changeEnv getLength` with an equivalent expression involving `asks`. However, to do so, you had to inspect the code of `getLength` and manually insert `changeEnv` every time the code used `ask`.

The point of `local` is to allow that transformation without having to rewrite all the code of `getLength`. Imagine an extreme scenario where instead of `getLength` we have a a very complex `action`, possibly also invoking other actions, so that in total we touch a few thousand lines of code.

Then we find a `local f action` we would like to replace. In such case, we would need to rewrite all of the code of `action` and its dependencies, just to insert `f` in all the right places. This is long, and also inefficient since in this way we recompute `f` many times.

`local` avoids that. Of course, strictly speaking, we do not have to use `local`, since we could break the abstraction by pattern matching on the `Reader` constructor (or abuse `runReader`) so that we can pre-compose `f` at the right spot. In doing so, however, we would have reimplemented `local`.

Further, note that `local` works not only on the simple `Reader a` monad, but on all monads of class `MonadReader`, where the `action`s could very well be complex ones.

Comment: However, `local` probably *shouldn't* be in that class!

Comment: @dfeuer Is there a way to define it in a generic way from the other class methods?

Comment: There is not, which is why it would be better to give it its own class. Its not necessarily easy (or possible?) to implement for all candidate instances.

Answer (score 1):

We have `asks f = local f ask` for any f, so it's true that you could
always write `asks` in terms of `local`.  Though normally you would
think of `asks f` as a shorthand for `fmap f ask`.

In the other direction however, consider something like

```
local changeEnv (do x <- getLength
                    y <- getReverse
                    pure (replicate x y))
```

How do you do this with `asks` in general?  You'd have to include the
entire body and put the environment into it explicitly:

```
asks ((\s -> replicate (length s) (reverse s)) . changeEnv)
```

You can always do this if you want because you can always translate
any Reader computation into ordinary functions.  But then you might as
well not use Reader at all.

This doesn't mean `local` is *necessary* either - it's just a
convenience for nesting readers, and you can always use `runReader`
directly instead like:

```
do s' <- asks changeEnv
   let x = runReader (do ...) s'
   ...
```

and I suppose you can then cram it all inside `asks` if you really want to, like

```
asks (runReader (do ...) . changeEnv)
```

but using `local` seems nicer.